# How complicated can Lipschitz domains be?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

A Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb R^n$ whose boundary $\partial\Omega$ is locally the graph of a Lipschitz continuous function. For example, any $C^1$ domain is Lipschitz and a cube is Lipschitz but not $C^1$.

An important parameter of a Lipschitz domain is its Lipschitz constant $\tau$. Its arctangent ($\arctan \tau$) corresponds to the maximum angle that the boundary of the domain can make. Thus the Lipschitz constant of the cube is $1$ but the Lipschitz constant of a $C^1$ domain can be chosen arbitrarily small. One of the interesting things of Lipschitz domains is that their regularity is "scale-invariant". A cube does not get "softer" after zooming in (at least when you zoom in at a corner).

I'd like to know:

- pathologic examples of Lipschitz domains, specially related with harmonic functions defined inside (or other topics like harmonic analysis).
- things that stop working when you go from $C^1$ domains to Lipschitz domains or that get much harder (for example, I know that the theory of layer potentials gets harder).
- also I'm curious whether given a point $x\in\partial\Omega$ we can find an open set $U \subset \partial\Omega$ such that $U$ is star-shaped with respect to $x$. Or if that's not possible, whether it's possible a.e. w.r.t. surface measure.

Comment: There is a short book by Dahlberg and Kenig called "HARMONIC ANALYSIS AND PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS" which explains the theory of layer potentials on Lipschitz boundaries and compares it to the smooth case.

Comment: I don't understand a thing in the third point. If $\Omega$ is a domain, then its boundary $\partial \Omega$ is closed respect to the ordinary "ambient topology" in $\Bbb R^n$, so should we intend the locution "we can find an open set $U \subset \partial\Omega$" as that if we can find a set $U$ which is open in the induced topology (i.e. is the intersection of an open set with $\partial\Omega$) or is it only a simple typo and we should really read "we can find an open set $U \subset \Omega$"?

Comment: Yes, I mean in the induced topology.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind is that Lipschitz functions coincide with C^1 functions outside a sets of arbitrarily small measure. Precisely, for a Lipschitz function $f:R^n \to R$ and any given $e>0$ there exists a C^1 function $g:R^n \to R$ such that the set where f is not equal to g has measure less than $e$. So, for a property that hold for C^1 domains we should ask whether it passes on to Lipchitz maps.